# Access Slow Processing of Sub-Query

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have created the following sub-query, but the processing time is really slow.  Can someone advise on how to quicken it up?

The processing time for qsel_TSMatch is relatively quick, so I have ruled this out as a cause.

```
SELECT *
FROM qsel_TSMatch
WHERE qsel_TSMatch.TSRef Not In (SELECT qsel_TSMatch.TSRef
           FROM qsel_TSMatch
          WHERE ((qsel_TSMatch.DQTest)="Yes"));
```

Comment: Could be the size of the table as well as the result of sub-query. The query looks similar to "SELECT * FROM T WHERE T.f2 <> 'Yes'", or do you want to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

This runs a lot quicker:

```
SELECT *
FROM qsel_TSMatch LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
  qsel_TSMatch.TSRef
FROM
  qsel_TSMatch
WHERE
  qsel_TSMatch.DQTest = "Yes"
  )   AS ztDQTest ON qsel_TSMatch.TSRef = ztDQTest.TSRef
WHERE (((ztDQTest.TSRef) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the same table in subquery, so this should provide the same result:

```
SELECT *
FROM qsel_TSMatch
WHERE 
    qsel_TSMatch.TSRef is null or  
    qsel_TSMatch.DQTest is null or 
    qsel_TSMatch.DQTest <> "Yes";
```